# Android: relative layout, put an element at the bottom

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Hello i have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/head"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:id="@+id/image1"
     />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/scan"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_below="@+id/image1" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mio_ad">
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

there's no way i can put my #mio_ad at the bottom: it remains at the top.
how can i?
thanks.

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentBottom` is only valid for the `RelativeLayout`, it does not have a place within `LinearLayout`, it would be flagged as an error within the Eclipse's Layout manager

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

use it!

Answer (score 3):

Use Below XML Code for that, it may help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/llayout" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/mio_ad">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/head"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:id="@+id/image1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/scan"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_below="@+id/image1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mio_ad" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Zak second element means which element?

Comment: Button.
However, resolved with only android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: but this is not proper solution.

Comment: @Zak if your imageview's height is fill_parent then bootom layout is not displaying.